# How do I compile and run with OpenJDK1.8 tools.jar

Tags: java

We have legacy code that has dependencies on Sun's tools.jar file so I have this in the artifact's pom.xml file

```
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.0</version>
                <scope>system</scope>
                <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

...and I see this in the *.java code

```
import com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine;
import com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachineDescriptor;
import com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException;
```

We are transitioning to OpenJDK1.8. What do I need to do to the pom.xml file(s) so the artifact builds with OpenJDK's tools.jar file, and the code to use the OpenJDK tools.jar file instead of Sun's during runtime?

Comment: I think you just need to adjust ${java.home} to reflect your OpenJDK location.

Comment: Even Maven documentation talks about tools.jar, https://maven.apache.org/general.html#tools-jar-dependency, but it's for the Sun version too. I need OpenJDK version. @rkosegi, that's one piece of the puzzle. I don't see where ${java.home} anywhere in any of my top-level (parent) pom.xml files. This does NOT answer all of my question though.